# (terminology) init.d script = LSB Init Script = System V Init script?

Tags: init.d, init

I'm having some trouble recognizing the different types of (traditional) system process management tools by name.

By "traditional" I mean before the likes of upstart, systemd, launchd etc. which I am learning as well. But still need to understand what technology/ies predates them.

## LSB init script

I see scripts in the `/etc/init.d/` directory with this signature:

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          scriptname
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start daemon at boot time
# Description:       Enable service provided by daemon.
### END INIT INFO
```

which were probably copied and pasted from here:

https://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts

## System V Init script

Looks like the same thing to me (too much for me to paste here):

https://github.com/fhd/init-script-template/blob/master/template

What is the relationship between this and System V Init scripts? Are they all the same thing, or is one a more modern version of the other? What's the difference in how they work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a system V init script.  The LSB header is just a comment block that sysvinit ignores, but provides the information that upstart/systemd need to figure out when they should run it.

Comment: So is the LSB standard a stepping stone between the old imperative System V Init paradigm and the declarative Upstart paradigm? I do recall reading that one of the issues with the classic System V Init scripts was that trying to restart failed jobs was clumsy (though still better than cron jobs as I have been for most of my needs).

Comment: @Sridhar-Sarnobat, that's pretty much it.